# Remove cloth sound from radio mics

Tags: radio, microphone, noise, reduction

Hello forum,

I was wondering, how do you guys deal with cloth sounds on radio mic recordings. Is there any way to get rid of this? I tried to deal with it with the normal noise reduction tools, but never really got completly rid of it.

Thanks,

Stirner

Comment: Prevention is better than Curing - find out how the cloth was created and make sure you don't receive recordings like this ever again.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but once that sort of interference is on the track it's nearly impossible to get rid of it completely. My advice would be to edit out as much as possible, filling in the edits with room tone or fill. Then for the noise that is over actual dialog, go find alternate takes you can steal syllables from and reconstruct the performance.

Comment: @Sound1844 Try to put in some clean foley above it and see if it covers it up a bit. But, if the cloth scratched the grill of the lapel and it's pretty much broad-band noise, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Yeah thats is what I thought, thanks. I will check out the foley advice though. 

Answer (score 1):

As Jay wrote, editing out the noise and find alt takes is the way to go.

Sometime, I had acceptable results using the Waves X-crackle (at extreme settings) to smooth out the noise (but you can lose some of the voice character/definition).

*By the way, the Waves x-crackle it's the only decrackle that I tried that can help with cloth/lapel noise, why? I think that what help, in those cases, are the "artifacts/distortion" that the plugin adds...*

You can also check out the izotope RX spectral repair, it could help.

Comment: I only have the iZotope de crackler. That has some effect on reducing it, but can't get rid of it. Will check out the waves plug in, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on Izotope RX (Spectral Repair) - if you're talking about post.

It saved a lot of noisy/damaged recordings I got delivered - can be quite a tedious job though, because you've got to be very careful.

In my opinion it's worth a try, though.

Comment: Never had good results with that one. Maybe I am doing something wrong. 